# Php Yii looping and comparison through object attributes

Tags: php, loops, object, yii, attributes

I'm doing a project in Yii, but i'm quite a newbie in php.
so my problem is i need to compare two models...and check each attribute whether they are the same or not. this is basically a php problem

i have two models say $model1 and $model2, i need to compare each attribute of each model..
i need to compare the models like:

```
 if ($model1->id == $model2->id){
        //do something here
 }
 if ($model1->value == $model2->value){
        //do something here
 }
```

but dynamically without really specifying the attribute id, as i want to loop and compare through each and every attribute

i have a code here that prints each of model1's attribute:

```
foreach ($model1 as $key => $value) {
            echo "$key => $value";
            echo "<br/>";

}
```

this code results to :

```
id => ...
value => ...
name => ...
```

how do i iterate through the two models and compare them? Thanks.help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: are they both objects of same Model??

Comment: yes :) basically each attribute will have same name, they will have both id and value,..and every attribute each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$model_arr1 = $model1->attributes;
$model_arr2 = $model2->attributes;

foreach($model_arr1 as $key => $value){
    if($model_arr1[$key] == $model_arr2[$key]){
        //do something
    }
}
```